# UML Sequence Diagram with PGF and Tikz produces "No shape named inst1 is known"

Tags: tikz-pgf, windows

I've recently started using LaTeX for all my documentation and can't believe I didn't do this sooner! It's so quick to get good-quality documentation produced, and the LaTeX format serves brilliantly as an interim format for conversion to others. I'm having a lot of fun :D

What I want to do presently is write a sequence diagram for a software build process. I'm using Tex Live 2011 and `pdflatex` (same result using plain old `latex`) in Cygwin on Windows XP to process my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepgflibrary{arrows} % for pgf-umlsd
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \begin{sequencediagram}
  \end{sequencediagram}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, it's very simple.

When I run this through `latex`/`pdflatex` I get:

```
) (./build-process.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

! Package pgf Error: No shape named inst1 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12   \end{sequencediagram}

?
```

What am I doing wrong? Furthermore, will my platform and software suffice to allow me to write sequence diagrams in LaTeX?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: the output is snipped somewhat to only show the error.

Comment: Does swapping around the `\uspackage{pgf-umlsd}` and the `\usetikzlibray{arrows}` help?

Comment: No, I placed `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` before `\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're using a somewhat old version from pgf-umlsd.sty which does not support empty diagrams. Version 0.6 should fix this (and does that in my case) and TeX Live 2011 uses 0.5 as far as I could see.

You could download it from: http://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! I manually copied the .sty in the .zip from your link to /texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf-umlsd/, after backing it up.